Querying GeoServer for workspace-specific local settings
GeoServer lets you set workspace-specific "local" settings:

How can I query GeoServer via its REST API to find out if a workspace has this setting enabled and get the settings?
/workspaces/{workspace}/settings.json returns some settings even if the checkmark is not checked:
{
  'settings': {
    'contact': {'id': 'contact'},
    'charset': 'UTF-8',
    'numDecimals': 4,
    'verbose': False,
    'verboseExceptions': False,
    'localWorkspaceIncludesPrefix': False,
    'showCreatedTimeColumnsInAdminList': False,
    'showModifiedTimeColumnsInAdminList': False
  }
}


Writing back that mapping to the same endpoint leads to the workspace using those settings, even if other global settings (e.g. different contact information) exist. And the checkbox is getting enabled.
Reading and writing back the same settings should not change the configuration so I think this is actually a bug: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-11361
